# mod rewrite to IIS rewrite rule

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite

I have a rule in my .htaccess which is

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ listing-search.php?profile=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

It basically looks for profile names after the domain (http://mysite.com/19KAREN) and extracts the profile details. I have tried to convert this to IIS7 rewrite using the available rewrite module and for the most part of it it works great however I have a blog at http://mysite.com/blog and when using the htaccess rewrite the blog is displayed (correct) however in IIS it is trying to fetch a profile named blog (incorrect).

If I were to add a slash to the end of the URL (http://mysite.com/blog/) then it works but I believe the client has sent out collateral without the slash so this isn't really an option.

I have tried adding a new rule to rewrite http://mysite.com/blog to .../blog/ but that isn't working either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out. Added a condition to the rule that if it's not a directory.